# How can I built 2UIDatepicker in 320width

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uipickerview, uidatepicker

Please check attached screenshot.
I am not able to built this screen.

Is there any way to develop ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There not two `UIDatePicker` but one [`UIPickerView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html) with two components.

Then they filled the components with an array of dates.

Comment: Looks like feasible option. Thanks